# Need help outputting from a vbs script

Tags: vbscript, directory, subdirectory

I found this script that says it can list the subfolders of a folder. How can I change this so that it will list the folders and save them to a text file?

I am using this to list user saved maps in a text file.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ShowFolderList(folderspec)
    Dim fs, f, f1, fc, s
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFolder(folderspec)
    Set fc = f.SubFolders
    For Each f1 in fc
        s = s & f1.name 
        s = s &  vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple lines:

```
Sub ShowFolderList(folderspec)
    Dim fs, f, f1, fc, s, logfile
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set logfile = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\logfile.txt", 8, True) ' Open a log file for appending
    Set f = fs.GetFolder(folderspec)
    Set fc = f.SubFolders
    For Each f1 in fc
        s = s & f1.name 
        s = s &  vbCrLf
    Next
    logfile.Write s ' Write content of s to log file
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```